# How to extract data from a website and display on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, web-crawler

I am trying to create a website similar to [this one](http://renthousemap.co.uk/rent/?location=london) where the user enters their criteria for the properties and the website grabs data that matches that criteria from websites such as [rightmove](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/), [zoopla](http://www.zoopla.co.uk/) etc. The data that is grabbed from these websites is then displayed on google maps, exactly as shown on that website.

Could someone point me in the right direction on where to get started please?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many of these property listing sites have APIs for retrieving easily parseable sets of data, which you can then format as you please for your map.

http://developer.zoopla.com/

For example, you can make an HTTP request for the following API endpoint URL (via AJAX or from your webserver), and you will receive an XML formatted list of properties and their attributes.

```
http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml?area=Oxford&api_key=XXXXXX
```

Then you can use the Google Maps API to inject the formatted data into an overlay. There are a lot of tutorials for this kind of thing floating around the web

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the reply. I have registered on the above website. Should I learn Python now to do what I want to do? Apologies, my background is that of JAVA, MATLAB and C. Haven't really done much web development.

Comment: Start with JavaScript, and then get familiar with a library like JQuery--it will be a good place to start for a webapp like you've described

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I have looked through tuts for JavaScript and JQuery and not quite sure what to do next.